# Create Alias on my Mac to Run KeePass File

Tags: macos, aliases

I've installed KeePass2.23 on my mac.  It is in my home directory ~KeePass-2.23/.  I'd like to create an alias to run this program.  Is this do-able?  The steps I use to run KeePass now are:

```
johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johndcowan$ cd KeePass-2.23/
johns-MacBook-Pro:KeePass-2.23 johndcowan$ mono KeePass.exe
```

Instead of cd-ing to the folder or typing in the path each time, I'd like to just use an alias and type one word:

```
johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johndcowan$ keepass
```

and have the program run.  In my .bash_aliases file I added:

```
alias keepass='mono ~KeePass-2.23/KeePass.exe'
```

This doesn't work.  I tried without the quotes also to no avail.
Any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried putting it in your ~/.bashrc file ?

Comment: I've added it to .bashrc, .bash_aliases and .profile.  I've done other aliases, but this one is a PIMA.

Answer (score 0):

Your alias should be:

```
alias keepass='cd ~/KeePass-2.23 && mono KeePass.exe'
```

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please accept as answer. If not, please say what happened. Thank you.